# log4j2 not generating logs on Staging machine

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have upgraded log4j 1 to log4j2 in our Spring project. Logs works fine on Dev and QA machines. But when we deploy it on Staging, logs are not being produced. When we turn on debug under  there are logs on startup. But it gets silent after that without error. This is my configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="my-project" packages="">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%x) [%t] %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </Console>

    <!-- Debug Logger -->
    <RollingFile name="DEBUG_LOG" fileName="/var/log/tomcat/my-project-backoffice-debug.log"
                 filePattern="/var/log/tomcat/my-project-backoffice-debug.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz">
        <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG"/>
        <PatternLayout  >
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%x) [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>

    <!-- Info Logger -->
    <RollingFile name="INFO_LOG" fileName="/var/log/tomcat/my-project-backoffice-info.log"
                 filePattern="/var/log/tomcat/my-project-backoffice-info.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz">
        <ThresholdFilter level="INFO"/>
        <PatternLayout  >
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%x) [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>

    <!-- Warn Logger -->
    <RollingFile name="WARN_LOG" fileName="/var/log/tomcat/my-project-backoffice-warn.log"
                 filePattern="/var/log/tomcat/my-project-backoffice-warn.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz">
        <ThresholdFilter level="WARN"/>
        <PatternLayout  >
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%x) [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>

    <!-- Error Logger -->
    <RollingFile name="ERROR_LOG" fileName="/var/log/tomcat/my-project-backoffice-error.log"
                 filePattern="/var/log/tomcat/my-project-backoffice-error.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz">
        <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR"/>
        <PatternLayout  >
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%x) [%t] %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG_LOG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="INFO_LOG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="WARN_LOG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="ERROR_LOG"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Thanks.

**Update: The Solution:**

One of older log4j dependency (transitive) was being loaded on Stage machine. Which is weird because the package got generated by Jenkins worked fine on Dev and QA machines. So I made sure to remove all transitive dependencies and it worked fine after that. These are the transitive dependencies I deleted.

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

Comment: You could remove the ThresholdFilters from the Appenders if you just add the level attribute with the corresponding value to the AppenderRef elements. I should also note that the info log file is also going to contain warn and error messages the way it is configured.

Comment: On QA machine I see all info logs in my-project-backoffice-info.log But my-project-backoffice-debug.log does contain all the logs as you have said.

Comment: I also removed ThresholdFilters and added Level attributes as you suggested. It did not make a difference. I still do not see logs for info. Only seeing logs for debug.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. You are seeing logs in the debug log but only at the debug level? Is that true even after startup?  You are not seeing logs in any of the other files? Are the files created? Given that the log level of both loggers is info you should be seeing debug logs.

Comment: I changed status="debug" and <Root level="debug"> only then debug log was being produced. So just to make things clear. I am seeing logs in debug  level even after startup. I am not seeing logs in Info level file after startup in any file (debug, info and error). These files are created. We delete the files before startup and these gets generated on startup.